# How to rsync between home computer and computer inside another network?

Tags: ssh, rsync

All the computers I use run Ubuntu. To work from home, I SSH from my home computer to my lab computer as follows:

```
# First a port knock is needed
joe@homepc> telnet ssh.university.edu 9000

# Next SSH to one of the external SSH servers of university
# This logs me into one of many SSH servers serving as interface
joe@homepc> ssh student7@ssh.university.edu

# Finally SSH to my lab PC inside university network
student7@university999> ssh joedude@labpc

# And I am in my labpc
joedude@labpc>
```

How do I use `rsync` to sync a directory on `labpc` with a directory on my `homepc`? Also, it would be awesome if there is some way to automate all of this so that I can rsync with just a single command from my homepc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this, however, because we want to run the rsync command on your home PC, I think the best way would be to create a tunnel from your home PC to the labpc, as follows:

```
joe@homepc> ssh -L 2222:127.0.0.1:2222 student7@ssh.university.edu

student7@university999> ssh -L 2222:127.0.0.1:22 joedude@labpc
```

Now, on your home PC, you should be able to ssh directly into the lab PC:

```
joe@homepc> ssh -p 2222 joedude@localhost
```

Once this is working, then you can build up an rsync script.

I would add the following lines to ~/.ssh/config

```
# Tunnel to labpc
Host labpc_tun
User joedude
Port 2222
# ProxyCommand  ... TODO: set up tunnel automatically
HostName 127.0.0.1
```

Now, you should be able to do (in a separate window, after first two ssh logins are done):

```
joe@homepc> rsync labpc_tun:/path-on-labpc/ /path-on-homepc/
```

There are lots more improvements you could make after this, but I would wait until you get the first part working, and then see how much automation you need.
To completely automate this you would need to use ssh-keygen to allow ssh logins without a password. You could also add more to .ssh/config for the first outgoing ssh leg. Using the ProxyCommand parameter in .ssh/config you could automate the entire thing.